# Nonlinear differential equation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-analysis, integro-differential-equations

Can someone give me  a hint to solve the next nonlinear diferential equation?
\begin{equation}
\frac{y'}{y}+\frac{f(t)+g(t)y}{h(t)+k(t)y}=0
\end{equation}

in some set where is well defined.

I know that if for example $k:=0$ this equation is reduced to a Bernoulli differential equation, and if $f=h$ and $g=k$ the soulution is $y=e^{-t}$. But I don't know how to solve this equation in a general case. Is there some way to solve it whitout using approximations when $f,h,g,k$, are constants, I mean
\begin{equation}
\frac{y'}{y}+\frac{f+gy}{h+ky}=0
\end{equation}
I just have taken a ordinary differential equations course so I don't know too much about nonlinear differential equations so if someone could give me some hint or an advice I really appreaciate it. Sorry for my english I am new writing in enlgish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your equation is an Abel equation of the second kind, which does not have a simple general solution. Simply multiply by $h(t)+k(t)y$ to get it to a more common form,
\begin{align}
[h(t)+k(t)y]y'+g(t)y^2+f(t)y=0.
\end{align}
There are several transformations you can do to bring it to 'simpler' forms, but the solution for $y(t)$ is quite involved except for a select amount of specific cases. [Here is a reference on the equation](http://eqworld.ipmnet.ru/en/solutions/ode/ode0126.pdf) (you have to transform $h+ky=ku$ to get it to the form on the page), and [papers such as this one](https://arxiv.org/abs/1503.05929) show the method for the general solution.